# Cognos Web Reports 7: Change Source of a Custom Report View

Tags: business-intelligence, cognos, cognos-bi

Is it possible to change the source of a custom report view in Cognos Web Reports?

We're using version 7.5.

Cheers

James

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically it is. I believe a small .Net or JAVA application with or without Cognos SDK would permit that. But version 7.5? That's ancient.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and yes - we're migrating at the moment :-)